# Working with octal permissions in bash

Tags: bash, permissions, octal

How do I get the masked (user) permissions from that permissions octal value?

Output should look like:

```
testfile1:
Permissions: 644
Masked Permissions: 600
testfile2:
Permissions: 750
Masked Permissions: 700
```

All I have now is:

```
for file in $@
do
    value=$(stat --printf '%a' $file)
    echo "permissions: $value"

    maskedvalue= # ???
    echo "permissions, masked: $maskedvalue"

done
```

Comment: Where is the 'mask' coming from? Is it the `umask` value? It looks as if you could do `maskedvalue=$(sed 's/..$/00/' <<< $value)`, but that's probably cheating.

Comment: Yes its the `umask` value, i don't want to change the permissions of the files though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it is `bash`, you can do:

```
 printf "%.4o\n" $(( $(stat -f '0%Lp' "$file") & ~$(umask) ))
```

at least, on Mac OS X, where `stat -f '%Lp'` means 'print the user, group, other permissions in octal'.
If you're on Linux, you'll need to translate that to the GNU `stat` syntax, which looks like it probably is:

```
printf "%.4o\n" $(( $(stat --printf '%a' "$file") & ~$(umask) ))
```

The spaces after `$((` and before `))` are not strictly needed in the sense that the shell knows what to do even if they are missing; likewise the spaces around the `&`.  OTOH, if anyone else has to read the code, you probably want those spaces there.

---

Test code:

```
file="./mode-file"
trap "rm -f $file; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

cp /dev/null "$file"

for mode in 777 755 644 640 444 440 400
do
    chmod $mode $file
    ls -l $file
    for umask in 002 022 027 033 037 077 177
    do
        umask $umask
        printf "$mode & ~$umask = %.4o\n" $(( $(stat -f '0%Lp' "$file") & ~$(umask) ))
    done
done

rm -f $file
trap 0
```

Example output:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov 11 20:57 ./mode-file
777 & ~002 = 0775
777 & ~022 = 0755
777 & ~027 = 0750
777 & ~033 = 0744
777 & ~037 = 0740
777 & ~077 = 0700
777 & ~177 = 0600
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov 11 20:57 ./mode-file
755 & ~002 = 0755
755 & ~022 = 0755
755 & ~027 = 0750
755 & ~033 = 0744
755 & ~037 = 0740
755 & ~077 = 0700
755 & ~177 = 0600
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov 11 20:57 ./mode-file
644 & ~002 = 0644
644 & ~022 = 0644
644 & ~027 = 0640
644 & ~033 = 0644
644 & ~037 = 0640
644 & ~077 = 0600
644 & ~177 = 0600
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov 11 20:57 ./mode-file
640 & ~002 = 0640
640 & ~022 = 0640
640 & ~027 = 0640
640 & ~033 = 0640
640 & ~037 = 0640
640 & ~077 = 0600
640 & ~177 = 0600
-r--r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov 11 20:57 ./mode-file
444 & ~002 = 0444
444 & ~022 = 0444
444 & ~027 = 0440
444 & ~033 = 0444
444 & ~037 = 0440
444 & ~077 = 0400
444 & ~177 = 0400
-r--r-----  1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov 11 20:57 ./mode-file
440 & ~002 = 0440
440 & ~022 = 0440
440 & ~027 = 0440
440 & ~033 = 0440
440 & ~037 = 0440
440 & ~077 = 0400
440 & ~177 = 0400
-r--------  1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov 11 20:57 ./mode-file
400 & ~002 = 0400
400 & ~022 = 0400
400 & ~027 = 0400
400 & ~033 = 0400
400 & ~037 = 0400
400 & ~077 = 0400
400 & ~177 = 0400
```

NB: Tested on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).  If you are using a GNU/Linux platform, you must change the `stat` command to use the notation that works on your machine.

Comment: Oh? What are you getting?  What does your `umask` produce as output? Does the output include a leading 0, which is crucial to producing octal data for the bitwise manipulation to work on.

Comment: Some leading 0, most not. 644 is 1204, 555 is 1051, 440 is 0650, and 750 is 1354.

Comment: OK; then you need to add a leading zero...`printf "%.4o\n" $(( $(stat -f '0%Lp' "$file") & ~0$(umask) ))`.  And if your `stat` doesn't produce a leading zero (the one on Mac OS X does not by default), you need to add one there, too.  That's the `0` in `'0%Lp'`, but if need be, you can add the 0 before the `$(stat...)`, like I just suggested with the `$(umask)`.

Comment: Awesome, `printf "%.4o\n" $(( 0$(stat --printf '%a' $file) & ~077 ))` gives me all the right output. Originaly though I wanted it without out the leading zero, but his may have to do.

Comment: You could use `"%.3o\n"` if the result should be just 3 digits, or `"%o\n"` if you don't mind getting 2 as the output for a 'write by others — only' file.

Comment: Alright I'm starting to get a hang of this. The bitwise operators are still throwing me off